# Aggregating Records Per Login Date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table storing user logins, which can be simplified to look like this:

```
| user | logindate           |
+------+---------------------+
| 001  | 2018-01-26 10:00:00 |
| 001  | 2018-01-26 11:00:00 |
| 001  | 2018-01-26 12:00:00 |
```

Similarly, I have a table recording activities completed by the user:

```
| user | activitydate        | activity  |
+------+---------------------+-----------+
| 001  | 2018-01-26 10:24:00 | survey    |
| 001  | 2018-01-26 10:30:00 | poll      |
| 001  | 2018-01-26 11:03:00 | poll      |
| 001  | 2018-01-26 12:08:00 | poll      |
| 001  | 2018-01-26 12:10:00 | survey    |
| 001  | 2018-01-26 12:12:00 | video     |
```

I would like to know the number of activities completed per user per login. Given the above example, I would expect results like this:

```
| user | latestLogin         | activityCount |
+------+---------------------+---------------+
| 001  | 2018-01-26 10:00:00 | 2             |
| 001  | 2018-01-26 11:00:00 | 1             |
| 001  | 2018-01-26 12:00:00 | 3             |
```

I have found one way to do this, which is to join each activity with the login table (where the login occurred *before* the activity), and get the max login per activity. I can demonstrated this using SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3c90d/8

However, I feel this solution is very slow. When I run this against a production environment, the query runs for far too long. There are nearly 85,000 login records for the time period I'm looking into, and a much much larger amount of activities.

What are some alternative solutions? Is there any way I could first subquery the login table to figure out the various login segments, and then tie each activity to those segments, for example?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: which indexes are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the logins using a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select max(l.logindate)
        from logins l
        where l.user = a.user and a.activitydate >= l.logindate
       ) as logindate
from activities a;
```

The rest is just aggregation.  I would use a subquery for this:

```
select user, logindate, count(*) as numactivities
from (select a.*,
             (select max(l.logindate)
              from logins l
              where l.user = a.user and a.activitydate <= l.logindate
             ) as logindate
      from activities a
     ) a
group by user, logindate;
```

The data in the SQL Fiddle differs from the data in the question, but [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c3c90d/12) is an example of how this works.

Comment: What makes a correlated subquery faster than the way I implemented it?

Comment: @AdamMc331 . . . A correlated subquery can make use of an index on `logins(user, logindate)` and does not need a second level of aggregation.